# igraph package for R not graphing based0 off an edgelist correctly

Tags: r, networking, social-networking, igraph

I am trying to import data about a network then graph in R (using the igraph package)

Here's my script:

```
links<-read.csv("FILEPATH")
edgetable <- links[,1:2]
g1=graph.edgelist(edgetable)
```

I get the error: "graph_from_edgelist expects a matrix with two columns"
Which seems like a straight forward error but my edgelist is a 2 column matrix.   (I've verified this--when I print out edgetable, there are only two columns.  It also indicates that the problem doesn't arise in reading the csv file)

Anybody encountered this issue before?  How could I fix this problem?
Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you verified that it is a two-column _matrix_

Answer (score 1):

As rawr suggested, I wasn't using matrices.
to solve this issue I added this line:

```
edgetable <- as.matrix(links)
```

Hope this helps for anyone else who runs into this silly problem! :)